# Unity2D: UnityException: Tag Enemy is not defined - FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy")

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a game project, and I'm trying to make tower that attacks enemies. When I start the game, there seems to be an issue with defining the enemy tag. As seen in the fragment of my script below, I wanted to define enemy by finding the game object that is named the same thing (Enemy) using FindGameObjectsWithTag. I am kind new with unity, so I don't seem to understand why the console wouldn't recognize that I defined "enemy" in the code below, giving me: UnityException: Tag Enemy is not defined, leading to this line below.

```
foreach(GameObject enemy in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy"))
```

PS: The enemy game object is controlled by another script (my enemy spawner script) where it spawns multiple 'enemy' clones under an Enemyspawner game object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in unity you need to add the tag... there,s a drop-down in the inspector (right above the transform component)... from there you need to add your custom tag, in this case `Enemy`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!!